# Issue with a "stray stroke" from Unit command while following YT tut. Pics included

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

I was following this [YouTube](https://youtu.be/pM5QL7NrhAw?t=4m22s) tutorial when I got stuck at the uniting part (timestamp in the link).

There was an added diagonal edge/stroke that appears that I can't seem to get rid of.

Does anyone else have this issue at all?

Here are 2 screenshots before and after the "unite" command. What's going on?

[image: Before]

[image: After]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ql4W.jpg

Answer (score 2):

See that center vertical path in the upper section??

Remove that, then unite/merge.

The spine of a stroke may remain at times depending upon how you expanded the stroke and what *exact* version of AI you are using.

I'm ***guessing*** that it's that spine creating the issue.

---

Sidenote: I *hate* when people link to video tutorials. **However**, *thank you* for doing it correctly with the time stamp. If everyone did that the world would be a better place `:)`

Comment: How do I remove that center dot? I know it's causing the issue, but I don't know how to remove it. It's only if I don't drag out the bar on the top right corner that I can "hide" the center dot so that it doesn't connect.

Comment: @Arrow The "center dot" appear to merely be a Live Corner handle and not an *actual* anchor. I was referring to the path running down the center of that top shape. Remove that with the Direct Selection tool (white arrow).

Comment: I give up. I think this version of Adobe doesn't work well with this tutorial. I've re-did the tutorial several times and same result. I also tried to remove the path like you said running down the center, however, that removes the rectangle body itself.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's a wrong step before Unite:

Menu Object > Expand > Select Fill and Stroke